# Postgres Update statements to DBT statements

Tags: dbt

I have a postgresql script like this and would like to convert this to a DBT statement without writing individual CTE's. Is there a way to use macro or similar method to do this code with less repetition.

In the update statements below the table name is same, only the where condition is varying.

The output should be

```
entity_id as product_id,delivery_time,is_vegan,ean
```

below is the sample SQL statements.

```
UPDATE
    products_temp x
SET
    delivery_time = cpev.value
FROM
     catalog_product  cpev
WHERE
    cpev.entity_id = x.product_id
    AND attribute_id = 140
    AND store_id = 0;

/* VEGAN OR NOT */
UPDATE
    products_temp x
SET
    is_vegan = TRUE
FROM
     catalog_product  cpeV
WHERE
    cpev.entity_id = x.product_id
    AND cpev.attribute_id in(196, 221)
    AND cpev.value ILIKE '%vegan%';
            
/*EAN*/
UPDATE
    products_temp x
SET
    ean = cpev.value
FROM
     catalog_product  cpev
WHERE
    cpev.entity_id = x.product_id
    AND attribute_id = 213;
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use CTEs? The DBT model concept is basically built on CTE logic. You can have one big CTE with using union, but I don't think it will help to make the code readable.